# Reading file without last x bytes

Tags: php, file

I want to read file without last x bytes in php, exactly like this:

```
$size = filesize($filename) - $x;
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, $size);
fclose($handle);
```

In my application, I will use this code a lot.

This works, but is it possible to do this more briefly and flexible, instead of using (filesize, fopen, fclose) each time?

Can `file_get_contents()` help? If so how do I use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example (the very simple solution)

```
$contents = substr(file_get_contents($filename), 0, -$x);
```

Just remove the last bytes/characters.

Answer (score 2):

It works with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$contents = file_get_contents($filename, false, null, 0, filesize($filename) - $x);
```